# Querying in client side minmongo on BSON NumberLong field

Tags: meteor, minimongo

I have a field named 'time' that holds nanoseconds timestamps as NumberLong in MongoDB. `NumberLong(212431234...)`

Trying to query it in the browser via

```
  time: {
    $gte: 2134234234...
  }
```

does not yield the expected results.

Is there a limitation on querying BSON fields on the browser minimongo?

I have tried converting the number in JavaScript to a BSON object via the BSON JavaScript library, but it does not seem the `gte` is working properly on that either.

How do I do a `gte` query on Numberlong on [Meteor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteor_%28web_framework%29) in the browser on a collection?

Comment: Can you post your entire query and what the results are?